# OpenCV 3.4.1 on Mac through Anaconda - - package not found

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

I'm running an Anaconda virenv that has successfully installed OpenCV ver.3.4.1.  From the python prompt I can `import cv2` and can confirm it's version per the command line below:

```
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:07:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.4.1'
```

However, in VSCode I run the following simple program and get an error:

```
import numpy as numpy
import argparse
import cv2

pass
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect_faces.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I don't understand why the command line import works, but the program from VSCode fails to import the same package.

There are multiple SO Q&A on this topic but they are all incredibly time/date sensitive and platform specific -- most deal with the situation where the package itself isn't recognized anywhere.  The closest question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836039/opencv-library-package-not-found) which is from 2015 and deals with the Android platform.  Any thoughts?

***Update***

The version installed should be 3.5.5, but I noticed that in the command prompt launched from anaconda it's shown as `Python 3.5.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.` while the version shown within VSCode is `Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.`. When I look at the available env in VSCode it shows some 2.7s and several 3.6 versions - including the one I'm using which is 3.6.5.

I've just done a new install of a fresh `Python 3.6` env and noticed that the command prompt reports `Python 3.6.6` while the output from a `sys` check reports `Python 3.6.5` -- again, both have the same executable path.

Comment: Is VSCode running your Anaconda Python 3.6.6? If you don't know how to check that, try adding `import sys; print(sys.version, sys.executable)` to the top of your script, and running the same thing at the command line, and tell us what they each say.

Comment: If that isn't the problem: are you using virtual environments (whether `conda env` or `virtualenv` or `venv`)? If so, is it possible that VSCode is using a different environment than the one you've activated on the command line? If you don't know how to check that, try adding `import sys; print(sys.path)`, and tell us what they each say.

Comment: @abarnet - you're on the right track...  the version installed should be 3.5.5, but I noticed that in the command prompt launched from anaconda it's shown as `Python 3.5.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.` while the version shown within VSCode is `Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.`.  When I look at the available env in VSCode it shows some 2.7s and several 3.6 versions - including the one I'm using which is 3.6.5.  Now that I know the problem - not sure how to fix.

Comment: From the command prompt it reports `Python 3.5.5`, from the VSCode output on the `sys print` it reports `Python 3.6.5` and from VSCode it reports `Python 3.6.6`.  Plus - all three are reporting the same executable path.  ?

Comment: OK, you have at least four copies of Python installed. The first question is: do you _want_ all of those other Pythons? If not, the simplest thing to do is to uninstall all but the one you want. Or, if you haven't really gotten started yet, maybe just uninstall _all_ of them, and then cleanly reinstall just the one you want. This is certainly going to be simpler than configuring everything to use the same Python and making sure you never accidentally use the other ones.

Comment: Or, alternatively, if you're _not_ using virtual environments, you may want to start doing so. But you'll need to read at least some basic tutorial stuff on setting up and using environments before that solves your problem.

Comment: @abarnet - I think the issue is a little more subtle than that - These are virtual environments in Anaconda.  After setting up a fresh environment - the command prompt in the one terminal window (launched from Anaconda GUI) doesn't match the terminal window from VSCode.  The path for both are the same, but they report back different versions of Python - I'm not sure how that is possible.  BTW - none reported through VSCode are 3.5.

Comment: OK, if you have multiple virtual environments in Anaconda, then it's just a matter of configuring either your default or per-project environment in VSCode to match the one you're using on the command line. (Which I don't know how to do; I've never used VSCode with conda env…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I was unable to replicate this same error, I did determine that it had to do with the installation of `numpy`.  For whatever reason, it originally installed and downgraded the Python version within the venv.  Then later when upgrading python it created a mismatch.  The fix was to recreate the venv with a pip install of all three packages in the same command line.  When installing all three at once the packages all reconcile - - I don't know if there was another variable - I couldn't recreate the original error.